# Possible to Apply Effect to Individual Textures in the Same Spritebatch?

Tags: c#, xna, hlsl, texture2d

I have a tile engine set up, all of which use the same `SpriteBatch`, `SpriteSortMode.FrontToBack`, so that I can use `float depth` for different layers, items on map, etc.

I wanted to apply an effect to individual layers, but after trying it just applied the effect to the entire spritebatch.

So is there a way to apply different effects to different textures in the same spritebatch?

Thanks,
Shyy

Comment: How are you applying effects?

Comment: I would put `effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();` before drawing each layer. I've heard in XNA 4.0 it's best to apply it through SpriteBatch.Begin(...), but as far as I know this isn't necessary for the question I'm asking.